# Copy table1 to new table and change field

Tags: mysql, sql

```
INSERT INTO `table2` SELECT * FROM `table1`;
```

how to insert all the fields from table1 to table 2 and modify the year,

sample is the "year" from 2016 to 2017

```
dr_year   
 2016
```

change it to all records with 2016 year to table2..

```
dr_year
 2017
```

Comment: List all the columns and change the one you want to change.

Comment: should i create another table sir?

Comment: can you give me sample sir

Comment: `INSERT INTO `table2` (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, 'New date value' FROM `table1`; `

Comment: sample is i have a table1 with fields , a, b,c, dr_year... and the year is 2017, so next year all the fields in table 1 will be copied to new table for 2018, is it necessary for me to create another table for 2018 or shoud i change the dr_year to 2018?, the 2017 will be replace and i cannot trace it. i don't know how, could you just give me suggestion sir.